# Symfony2: class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

Error occurs when attempting to persist a one-to-many relationship.  In particular, a client may have multiple household members; a given household member is associated with one and only one client.  [I am new to Symfony so errors are expected!]  Your guidance gratefully accepted.

N.B. Alternate controller snippet below yields integrity constraint error by trying to set the client's id in the household table to null.

#### Clients Entity snippet

```php
namespace Mana\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Mana\AdminBundle\Entity\Clients
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Clients
{
    protected $members;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }

    public function setMembers(ArrayCollection $members)
    {
        $this->members = $members;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Household", mappedBy="clients")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EthDesc", inversedBy="clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
```

#### Household Entity snippet

```php
namespace Mana\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mana\AdminBundle\Entity\Household
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="household")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mana\AdminBundle\Entity\HouseholdRepository")
 */
class Household {

    /**
     * @var integer $hid
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients", inversedBy="members")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EthDesc", inversedBy="members")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
```

#### ClientsType snippet

```php
    ->add('members', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new HouseholdType(),
        'allow_add' => true, 
        'by_reference' => false,
        'cascade_validation'  => true,
        ));
```

#### Controller snippet

```php
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Clients();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientsType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->persist($entity->getMembers());
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clients_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
}
```

#### Alternate controller snippet

```php
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Clients();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientsType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        foreach ($entity->getMembers() as $member)
        {
            $em->persist($member);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clients_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
```

Comment: @Wouter-j: what was your edit?  On another note, modifying $em->persist($entity->getMembers()); to a foreach loop results in an integrity constraint error related to the member having the client's id as null.  Huh? I thought this would be magic.

Comment: I would not worry about the edits much.  There seems to be a small team which edits pretty much every post.  I guess they are trying to enforce some standard.  It's very annoying.

Comment: With respect to the problem, I can't really tell from your posted code what is going on.  I would suggest making a Command object and then just mess around with creating and persisting a few entities until your model works as needed.  That will cut out all the form stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The times I have gotten this to work, I did not

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

I just

```
$this->field = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

in my constructor.

Also, you may want to consider adding Household (which appear to be the members in clients) as an entity form:

```
->add('members', 'entity', array(
    'type' => new HouseholdType(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'by_reference' => false,
    ));
```

Comment: The answer includes necessary items.  It is not by itself sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I (incorrectly) tried to access the ToMany relation as it was ToOne relation ([similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330451/4837606)).